# Pandas Dataframe - sort list element by date, when date is substring of element

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to sort data in each cell in column named SESSIONS, based on date (YYYY_MM_DD) and this date is inside elements (strings) forming list. SESSIONS column can have various numbers of sessions and can be also empty. In one cell of SESSIONS colum there is list of sessions (like in "li" I put as an example for testing).
Below is how it worked OK when doing it outside df (2019_04_20 appears as latest):

```
li = ['WE233JP_2015_03_03__13_31_21','WE238JP_2019_04_20__16_40_59','WE932LT_2017_10_12__08_35_49']
li.sort(key = lambda x: datetime.strptime(re.sub(r'^([^_]+)_(.+)__(.+)', r'\2', x), '%Y_%m_%d'))
print(li)
```

When I try to apply it on df with below codes (2 attempts):

```
df['sessions'] = df.sessions.fillna('NULL').sort_values().apply(lambda x: sorted(datetime.strptime(re.sub(r'^([^_]+)_(.+)__(.+)', r'\2', x), '%Y_%m_%d')))
df['sessions'] = df.sessions.fillna('NULL').sort_values().apply(lambda x: sorted(re.sub(r'^([^_]+)_(.+)__(.+)', r'\2', x)))
```

In both cases I got an erorr: *TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object*

Simple non-date sorting like below works OK:

```
df['sessions'] = df.sessions.fillna('NULL').sort_values().apply(lambda x: sorted(x))
```

Any suggestions how to sort df on extracted part of string formatted as date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try series `map` with custom sort key function

```
Sample `df`:
     sessions
0  [WE233JP_2015_03_03__13_31_21, WE238JP_2019_04_20__16_40_59, WE932LT_2017_10_12__08_35_49]
1  NaN

import re    
sort_func = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(re.findall(r'^[^_]+_(.+)__.+', x)[0], 
                                    format='%Y_%m_%d', errors='coerce')
df['sorted_sessions'] = df.sessions.map(lambda y: sorted(y, key=sort_func) 
                                                  if y is not np.nan else y)

Out[1455]:    
sessions  \
0  [WE233JP_2015_03_03__13_31_21, WE238JP_2019_04_20__16_40_59, WE932LT_2017_10_12__08_35_49]
1  NaN                                                                                  

sorted_sessions
0  [WE233JP_2015_03_03__13_31_21, WE932LT_2017_10_12__08_35_49, WE238JP_2019_04_20__16_40_59]
1  NaN
```

Comment: SESSIONS column can have various numbers of sessions. It is almost never one session in one cell. It is list of sessions in one cell.

Comment: So, every cell is a list and some lists has multiple sessions while others may have 1 session or empty list? If that is the case, how do you want to sort within each cell and between cells? Could you provide a sample dataframe represent what you describe?

Comment: I only need to sort it within cell (list). I have added more info to my question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for support! I wonder why my 2 approaches I've mentioned in question did not work. Is it because "sorted()" method works ony on strings?

Comment: @zwornik: you are welcome. The error is from `re.sub(r'^([^_]+)_(.+)__(.+)', r'\2', x)`. You call `apply` on column `sessions` which is `series.apply`. Therefore, `x` of apply is the value of each cell. Each cell of `sessions` is a list. Python `re.sub` works on string or byte-like object. You pass list to it, so it errors out that error.